# Python: ModuleNotFound error when starting script manually

Tags: python, environment-variables

When I double-click the script to run it raises ModuleNotFound error. However, when I execute `python main.py`, the script works just fine. What can be causing it? I have a fresh 3.6.1 installation.

[image]

The `telebot` module is successfully installed and working.
Here's to clarify:

- When I double-click or run `main.py` from console, the script throws an error because it cannot find a module. (probably because it runs from a distant folder)
- When I run `python main.py` from the same folder the script works well. All modules are recognized and loaded. (my guess is that `python` command runs `python.exe` which is located where all of the modules are)
- My Path environment variable is pointing to the correct folder.
- I only have one python installation and one version.

Comment: Can you provide a MWE?

Comment: @BudoZindovic It's not code-related but rather environment-related. If I use `main.py` it doesn't work (probably because it starts inside a folder), if I use `python main.py` it works (because I start it from where the python.exe is)

Comment: Maybe you have more than one python distribution installed?

Comment: @BudoZindovic Nope. Just checked. Python 3.6.1 32bit, Python 3.6.1 64bit, Python Launcher. The Path environment variable is pointing to the correct folder.

Comment: Maybe you have associated the file to one python version (e.g. `Python 3.6.1 32bit`) but your package is installed in `Python 3.6.1 64bit`. Did you install the package in both `Python 3.6.1 32bit` and `Python 3.6.1 64bit`?

Comment: @BudoZindovic It came this way. Most of the programs I use automatically install two versions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149044/discussion-between-budo-zindovic-and-weary-adventurer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have installed both 32 bit and 64bit Pythons but have installed a package in only one of them. You can one of the following:

- uninstall the one that doesn't have the package installed and add the remaining one to the path variable, or
- you can install package in both 32bit and 64bit python.